# C++: Buoyancy program does not output as planned

Tags: c++, function, exponent

I attempted to make a program that asks for the input for the radius of a sphere, and the weight of the sphere. it uses these inputs to calculate the buoyancy of the sphere and the program determines whether or not it can float in water. However, I keep getting "6.95207e-308", no matter what my inputs are

These are the instructions for the programming assignment:

> "Buoyancy is the ability of an object to float. Archimede's Principle
>   states that the buoyant force is equal to the weight of the fluid that
>   is displaced by the submerged object. The buoyant force can be
>   computed by:
>
> buoyant force = (object volume) times (specific gravity of the fluid)
>
> If the buoyant force is greater than or equal to the weight of the
>   object then it will float, otherwise it will sink.
>
> Write a program that inputs the weight (in pounds) and radius (in
>   feet) of a sphere and outputs whether the sphere will sink or float in
>   water. Use 62.4 lb/cubic foot as the specific weight of water. The
>   volume of a sphere is computed by (4/3)π times the radius cubed."

This is my code:

```
//Written by: Edward Santiago
//Assignment: HW_03_No14.cpp
//Class: CO SCI 243
//Date: October 17, 2014
//Description: Prime Numbers
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double sphere_volume (double);
double buoy_force (double,double);
int main ()
{

    double rad,volume,force,buoyancy;
    double weight;
    double water = 62.4;
    cout << "~~Buoyancy calculator~~" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the radius of your sphere" << endl;
    cin >> rad;
    cout << "Please enter the weight of your sphere" << endl;
    cin >> weight;
    volume = sphere_volume(rad);
    buoyancy = buoy_force(volume,weight);
    cout << "The force of your sphere is "<<force<<endl;
    if (force <= water)
        cout << "Your sphere will float in the water"<<endl;
    else
        cout <<"Your sphere will sink :( "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
double sphere_volume (double radius)
{
    double vol;
    vol = ((4/3) * (M_PI) * (pow(radius,3)));
    return vol;
}
double buoy_force (double vol,double weight)
{
    double force;
    force = vol * weight;
    return force;
}
```

Comment: You should enable warnings, it would have informed you of this problem. For *gcc/clang* use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize force.

```
buoyancy = buoy_force(volume,weight);
cout << "The force of your sphere is "<<force<<endl;
```

Change the assignment to `force = buoy_force(volume, weight)`.

Comment: you forgot to add the "l" in volume, but it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the big answer to "buoyancy" and then printed out "force".

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
force=buoyancy;
```

just before printing `force`. This is because `force` is uninitialized and you are trying to print it.